# Solr 9: Dense Vector input being converted to pdouble format

Tags: python, solr, knn, pysolr, solr9

I passed a dense vector to Solr9 for indexing but it takes the values passed and put them into a variable whose data type is pdoubles. I have made changes to the managed-schema.xml to identify the field named `vector` as a `knn_vector`, but solr dynamically created a new field named `vectors` of type `pdouble`.

Lines that i added to managed-schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="knn_vector" class="solr.DenseVectorField" vectorDimension="768" similarityFunction="euclidean"/>

<field name="vector" type="knn_vector" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Dynamically added lines by solr itself

```
<field name="vectors" type="pdoubles"/>
```

For reference my code

```
embedder = SentenceTransformer('distilbert-base-nli-stsb-mean-tokens')
corpus = [documents[d]['paragraph'] for d in documents]
corpus_embeddings = embedder.encode(corpus, convert_to_tensor=False)

d=0
for row in corpus_embeddings:
   documents[str(d)]['vectors']=np.array(row).tolist()
   d=d+1
```

```
import pysolr
solr = pysolr.Solr('http://localhost:8983/solr/VectorPilotRun/', always_commit=True, timeout=10)

results=solr.search("{!knn f=vector topK=10}"+str(documents['500']['vectors']))
print("Saw {0} result(s).".format(len(results)))
for result in results:
    print("The details are : '{0} {1} {2}'\n.".format(result['id'],result['paragraph'],result['paragraph_num']))
```

The result of this search is `null`.

When I try to query the `knn_vector` field that is `vector` field it shows no results. I believe this is because all the data is associated to the `vectors(pdouble)` field instead of `vector(knn_vector)`.

How do I add data so that it is stored in the correct field and type and not dynamically changed to another type? I have used pysolr to add data and the vector are list of float values.

Comment: It seems you're submitting your values as a field name named `vectors` (which is why Solr creates the field) and not as `vector` which is what you created. Since you didn't include any information about how you're indexing content, it's impossible for anyone to say exactly what is happening, but that would explain what you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I later realized that an extra 's' in `vectors`  instead of using `vector` was causing this issue. Such silly typo/mistakes are difficult to get your head around.

Answer (score 1):

Beside the managed-schema.xml  you should add a separate file schema.xml in the config dir before creating solr collection

For example,

```
<schema name="visual-search1" version="1.0">
  <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
  <!-- vector-based field -->
  <fieldType name="knn_vector" class="solr.DenseVectorField" vectorDimension="512" similarityFunction="cosine" omitNorms="true"/>
  <fieldType name="long" class="org.apache.solr.schema.LongPointField" docValues="true" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
  <!-- basic text field -->
  <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>

  <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="false"/>
  <field name="image_path" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="gender" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="article_type" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="color" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="sub_category" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="feature" type="knn_vector" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
  <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

</schema>
```